# Erro com JSON.parse no react-native + axios

Tags: react-native, axios

Estou utilizando axios para buscar dados de uma API em PHP.
Recebo uma resposta com os dados esperados no react-native, no entanto ao utilizar a função `JSON.parse()` recebo o erro:

> "[SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '']".

Já validei a resposta que recebo utilizando a ferramenta disponível em `https://jsonlint.com/`.

A resposta completa que recebo é:

```
    {"config": {"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter], "baseURL": "baseurl.com.br", "data": "{\"data\":{\"codPedido\":\"67912\",\"codLoja\":\"3\",\"action\":\"getPedido\"}}", "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "post", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "url": "/request.php", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}, "data": "{\"status\":\"success\",\"type\":true,\"data\":{\"codLoja\":\"3\",\"codPedido\":\"67912\"}}", "headers": {"connection": "Keep-Alive", "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "date": "Mon, 23 Nov 2020 18:27:54 GMT", "keep-alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "server": "Apache", "vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent"}, "request": {"DONE": 4, "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2, "LOADING": 3, "OPENED": 1, "UNSENT": 0, "_aborted": false, "_cachedResponse": undefined, "_hasError": false, "_headers": {"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}, "_incrementalEvents": false, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {"connection": "Keep-Alive", "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "date": "Mon, 23 Nov 2020 18:27:54 GMT", "keep-alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "server": "Apache", "vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent"}, "_method": "POST", "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://baseurl.com.br/request.php", "_requestId": null, "_response": "{\"status\":\"success\",\"type\":true,\"data\":{\"codLoja\":\"3\",\"codPedido\":\"67912\"}}", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "baseurl.com.br/request.php", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": {"Connection": "Keep-Alive", "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "Date": "Mon, 23 Nov 2020 18:27:54 GMT", "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "Server": "Apache", "Vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent"}, "responseURL": "baseurl.com.br/request.php", "status": 200, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}, "status": 200, "statusText": undefined}
```

Tento utilizar o JSON.parse na propriedade data:

```js
    api.post('/request.php', {
                data: { codPedido, codLoja, action: 'getPedido' },  
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(JSON.parse(data.data));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
```

Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe o que posso estar fazendo errado?

Versões utilizadas

- react-native: 0.63.3
- axios: 0.21.0
- php da API: 5.6.40
- Testando em: LG K50S (android 9)

Comment: Creio que este erro se deve ao fato de voce fazer um `JSON.parser` desnecessario. O Axios ja trata as respostas pra voce lhe servindo um objeto javascript o qual voce ja pode usar, para que nao precise realizar o parser manualmente, logo voce esta fazendo um parser de um objeto javascript e nao de um json.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Verifiquei o tipo de `data.data` utilizando `typeof data.data` e a resposta é 'string'. Assim, não consigo acessar as propriedades como `type` e `status`